# Client HTTP Java

Tags: java, http, file

I am searching for an HTTP java client optimized for downloading and uploading files. We do a lot of download and upload of files (more 10 Go by days / 10000 files by day).

1. Is there some client which permits download on the fly (writing directly file on filesystem not in memory)?
2. Which protocol is used for download and upload: HTTP 1 or HTTP 2 (with multiplexing)?
3. There are some ways to optimize downloading and uploading files? I think to multithread with asynchronous download and upload, but there is some warning to using this? Other technical way?

Comment: Perhaps this article would help: [*Comparison of Java HTTP Clients*](https://reflectoring.io/comparison-of-java-http-clients/). Written 2021-11. Examines four libraries, including [*JEP 321: HTTP Client*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/321) bundled with Java 11+.

Comment: This article, [*Java 11: a New Way to Handle HTTP and WebSockets in Java!*](https://dzone.com/articles/java-11-a-new-way-to-handle-http-and-websockets-in) by Adrian D. Finlay, seems to show downloading to a file using the JEP 321 client: `Files.copy(HTTP_STREAM, new File("response2.json").toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);`